# What do i put as a path when i didnt download anything

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to test something with edge but when i wright the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

service = Service(verbose = True)

driver = webdriver.Edge(service = service)
```

It gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    service = Service(verbose = True)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'executable_path'
```

Does anyone know why this happens. Also i dont know what it means by path because i dont have anything downloaded or any folders or such.

Comment: I think it is asking for path of microsoft edge's executable.

Comment: @nobleknight What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
s = Service('C:\Path_to_the_file\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = s)
```

Comment: it gives me a new error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service = s)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'